# Angular 8 mat table sorting not working with multi table

Tags: angular, typescript

i still new with angular and not familiar with it, I have face a problem regarding mat table for sorting. i have multi table in one page, each table we separated with mat tab, the problem is , the sorting only working on first table("crane master list") at first tab, the rest is not working,

ts

```
import { MatSort,Sort } from '@angular/material/sort';

  @ViewChild(MatSort, { static: true }) sortCrane: MatSort;
  @ViewChild(MatSort, { static: true }) sortLifeboat: MatSort;

 preloadData() {
//fetch data from api
    this.masterlistService.getCrane().subscribe(res => {
      this.craneDataSource = new MatTableDataSource(res);
      this.craneDataSource.sort = this.sortCrane;
    });
    this.masterlistService.getLifeboat().subscribe(res => {
      this.lifeboatDataSource = new MatTableDataSource(res);
      this.lifeboatDataSource.sort = this.sortLifeboat;
    });
}
```

html

```
  <mat-tab-group style='min-height:37rem;' (selectedTabChange)="onClickTab($event)">
 <mat-tab label="Crane Masterlist">
      <table mat-table [dataSource]="this.craneDataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8" style="margin-top: 3.5rem;" matSort  (matSortChange)="announceSortChange($event)">
   <ng-container matColumnDef="Region">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="thead-dark" mat-sort-header> Region </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let item"> {{item.Region}} </td>
        </ng-container>
//....etc
</table>
  </mat-tab>
 <mat-tab label="Lifeboat Masterlist">
       <table mat-table [dataSource]="this.lifeboatDataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8" style="margin-top: 3.5rem;"
        matSort (matSortChange)="announceSortChange($event)">
   <ng-container matColumnDef="Region">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="thead-dark" mat-sort-header> Region </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let item"> {{item.Region}} </td>
        </ng-container>
//....etc
</table>
  </mat-tab-group>
  </mat-tab>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have more than one `matSort` in one file, using [`@ViewChild`](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild) with just class name won't work. Use template reference variable instead.

```
<table #craneTable mat-table [dataSource]="this.craneDataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8" style="margin-top: 3.5rem;" matSort  (matSortChange)="announceSortChange($event)"><!-- ... --></table>
<table #lifeboatTable mat-table [dataSource]="this.lifeboatDataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8" style="margin-top: 3.5rem;" matSort (matSortChange)="announceSortChange($event)"><!-- ... --></table>
```

---

```
  @ViewChild("craneTable") sortCrane: MatSort;
  @ViewChild("lifeboatTable") sortLifeboat: MatSort;
```

---

Alternatively, you may also use [@ViewChildren](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren)

Comment: thx for answer, there some change  @ViewChild("craneTable", { read: MatSort, static: false }) sortCrane: MatSort;.. thx for the idea... i appreciate